# DH groups support for isakmp policy

Tags: router, cisco-asa, security, ipsec, tunnel

When configuring a site-to-site VPN tunnel between the ASA and Cisco router, I have queries around the ISAKMP policy. As per [Cisco documentation for ASA](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/security/asa/asa72/configuration/guide/conf_gd/ike.html), the crypto isakmp policy groups available are 1, 2, 5, and 7. Also, reading the official [Security for VPNs with IPsec Configuration Guide](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios-xml/ios/sec_conn_vpnips/configuration/xe-3s/sec-sec-for-vpns-w-ipsec-xe-3s-book/sec-cfg-vpn-ipsec.html), it says DH groups 1, 2, and 5 are no longer recommended and to go for group 14 or higher. So my question is: what group is to be configured on the router end so there is no issue with the tunnel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should pick the highest group number that both devices have in common.  The strength of the key doesn't matter if both ends of the tunnel can't use it.

Comment: Newer versions of ASA also support more modern DH groups via IKEv2 configuration. Updating the ASA is recommended, if possible.